# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT' AlterProcedure to add BIT default 0

Tags: sql-server, procedure, bit, alter

I want to alter my procedure to add a parameter as BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, but I have an error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MY_PROCEDURE]
(
@tos_id int,
@website_name VARCHAR(15),
@toDelete BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)
AS BEGIN [stuff] END
```

Comment: Use `@toDelete BIT = 0`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Thanks, it will just put 0 as Default value ?

Comment: Most of the SQL Server documentation for T-SQL statements has a section at the start *detailing* the allowed syntax. [ALTER PROCEDURE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax) is no different in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MY_PROCEDURE]
 (
  @tos_id int,
  @website_name VARCHAR(15),
  @toDelete BIT NOT NULL=0
 )
 AS BEGIN [stuff] END
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  Giorgos Betsos

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UPDATE_DIGITAL_CALENDAR_OTHER]
(
@tos_id int,
@website_name VARCHAR(15),
@Comment VARCHAR(100),
@Status BIT,
@ToDelete BIT = 0
)
AS
BEGIN [stuff] END
```